# Is there a social class shift in "raff" to "raffish"?

Tags: etymology, social-interaction

I have just watched a historical documentary on the life of Edward VII in which it is explained how the heir to Queen Victoria, both as Prince Of Wales and later as King had been a quintessential exemplar of the *raffish* mood of the late nineteenth century.

The OED examples of *raffish* indicate that it is people like James Bond who are *raffish*.

> 1906   Bookman Oct. 179/2   One's attention is riveted upon Jessie
>   Incell, a woman reporter, for she inevitably invites comparison with
>   Nancy Olden, the somewhat raffish heroine of In the Bishop's Carriage.
>
> 1937   Harper's Mag. June 101/1   The raffish, free-for-all girl finds
>   a devoted husband.
>
> 1958   Spectator 27 June 831/2   [He] displayed a certain raffish
>   elegance in his long, dark jacket and dog-tooth trousers.
>
> 1989   Observer 3 Sept. (Colour Suppl.) 24/1   Sag Harbor has a more
>   raffish, agreeable, even faintly Bohemian air.
>
> 1997   Daily Tel. 27 June 21/1   In a James Bondish sort of way,..[he]
>   combines a raffish charm and an aristocratic sang-froid.

However the etymology of *raffish* has it that it was formed within English from *raff* - as in *riff-raff*.

> Etymology:  Formed within English, by derivation. Etymons: raff n.3,
>   -ish suffix1

Now the *riff-raff* quite clearly are not the sort of people who would tend to early-twentieth century *raffish* behaviour such as that indulged in by Edward VII - visits to the high-class brothels of Paris, the gambling casinos of Monte Carlo and Biarritz, high class courtesans, massive overindulgence in fine food, elegant drinking, trade-mark cigars, and beautiful heiresses.

So how did *raff* (from *riff-raff*) get to *raffish*.

Comment: can you give the etymology and link? also definition? etymonline's definition seems different from yours

Comment: @Mitch Sorry. I have now put the etymology in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Did you see etymonline a version?

Comment: @Mitch Etymonline seems to say very much the same thing as the OED.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=raffish gives "disreputable, vulgar" which accords with riff-raff but not with your (and my) feelings of the word which is more street-wise elegant. Anyway, if raffish means shabby-chic, I think that is the connection between riff-raff and any use by/for higher classes. It still means something lower-classish, but maybe often paired with a higher class term for contrast. [Of all the definitions of raffish I'm seeing](https://www.google.com/search?q=raffish+definition), none leave the standard view of the lower classes.

Comment: @Mitch *Riff-raff* and *raffish* certainly conjure very different images. Edward VII may not have minded being regarded as *raffish*. But I doubt he would have cared to have been seen as *riff-raff*.

Comment: It should be noted that "raffish" is pretty much unknown in modern US English.

Comment: @HotLicks It is not much used in Britain either, except when describing Edwardian characters. It is to that period that the word belongs.

Answer (score 1):

In William Safire's column *On Language*, in *The New York Times* (November 19, 2000) in the article [*Riff and Raffish*](http://partners.nytimes.com/library/magazine/home/20001119mag-onlanguage.html):

According to Safire *raffish*

> first appeared in a letter from Jane Austen in 1801: "He is as 
>   raffish  in his appearance as I would wish every disciple of Godwin to
>   be." William Godwin was a brilliant, unkempt Dissenter, husband of the early feminist Mary Wollstonecraft, and he struck admirers as delightfully unconventional.

Riff raff is older:

> "You would inforce upon us the old  riffe-raffe  of Sarum," wrote the
>   poet Milton in 1641.

The raff of raffish came from the raff of riff raff.  Riff raff are rabble, clearly lower class, and the raffish are the vaguely disreputable of the upper classes.

Saffire:

> Riff  and  raff  are half-rhyming quasi-nouns from the Old French 
>   rifler,  "to rifle, ransack," and  raffler,  "to ravage, snatch away,"
>   applied to things of little value.

I deleted this after I wrote it last week, but Ricky just provided a Missing Link, so I undeleted it. Someone (Mrs Bennet?) probably sniffed that Mr. Godwin looked like riff-raff and Miss Austen then coined raffish.

Comment: Mawkish is what they all were. Except for Safire, of course. Some of his articles were pretty good.

Comment: And by the way what's this newfangled obsession everyone's afflicted with, with deleting one's own comments? A new trend? What did I miss?

Comment: @Ricky I incorporated my comment into my answer.  And, very occasionally, I later decide a comment of mine was rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

**-ish**

adjectival suffix, from Old English -isc, common Germanic [blah-blah-blah] Colloquially attached to hours to denote approximation, 1916.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ish?s=t

The suffix must have experienced a sharp rise in popularity at the beginning of the 20th Century. Which, I would imagine, gave us ***ghoulish***, ***churlish***, ***girlish***, ***roguish***, etc.

Another suffix, ***-y***, was very popular in the 1990's, briefly enriching our vernacular with such pearls as **science-y**, **Christmas-y**, and **relationship-y**.